# Is my understanding of tensorflow v1 session correct?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
self.sess = tf.Session()
_, self.cost = self.sess.run(
    [self._train_op, self.loss],
    feed_dict={self.s: batch_memory[:, :self.n_features],
    self.q_target: q_target}
)
```

The order of execution as I understand it is:

```
self.cost=self.sess.run(
    [self.loss],feed_dict={self.s: batch_memory[:, :self.n_features], self.q_target: q_target})
_=self.sess.run([self._train_op],feed_dict={self.loss:self.cost})
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution is sequential. Graph will be created in the same order the operations are defined inside the session.

Simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = 4
y = 5
add_op = tf.add(x, y, name='Add')
mul_op = tf.multiply(x, y, name='Multiply')
pow_op = tf.pow(add_op, mul_op, name='Power')
useless_op = tf.multiply(x, add_op, name='Useless')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    pow_out, useless_out = sess.run([pow_op, useless_op])
```

When fetch `pow_op` operation, it will first run the `add_op` and `mul_op` to get their output tensor and then run `pow_op` on them to compute the required output value. In other words `useless_op` will not be executed as it's output tensor is not used in executing the `pow_op` operation.